# Error calling action through getJSON in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am calling a controller action through $.getJSON() method but i dont know why the action is not calling.

```
$.getJSON("/Home/Index", { ID:id }, function(){
});
```

But when i change this to

```
$.getJSON("/Home/Index/s", { ID:id }, function(){
});
```

it works fine. I have check my routing and i did not find any problem there. What can be the issue?

Comment: Could you show your routing configuration?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
               "GetPostTypeChild",
               "Home/Index",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
               );

Answer (score 1):

That's really really weird.
I've tried your script and the only problem I can see is the fact that ASP.NET MVC2 can't return json data when the call is a GET. It's been blocked for security reasons.

If you try to trace your call with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), you might notice that the response is something like this:

***"This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."***

If you want to enable the return data, anyway, you can force it:

```
return (Json(<your object>, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
```

or do a POST. You can find more infos [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).

Comment: Yes i face that issue but my problem is that the Index action is not calling.

Comment: Even with AllowGet, I found that it is called only one.. To overcome, I used [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]

Comment: @Fraz Sundal: it seems to me that your problem might be with the routing. Is this the only route defined? routes.MapRoute( "GetPostTypeChild", "Home/Index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } );